# Search for word (from list of words) in line (from list of lines) and append values to new list. Python

Tags: python, list, function, search, findall

If you had a list of names . . .

```
query = ['link','zelda','saria','ganon','volvagia']
```

and a list of lines from a file

```
data = ['>link is the first','OIGFHFH','AGIUUIIUFG','>peach is the second',
'AGFDA','AFGDSGGGH','>luigi is the third','SAGSGFFG','AFGDFGDFG',
'DSGSFGAAA','>ganon is the fourth','ADGGHHHHHH','>volvagia is the last',
 'AFGDAAFGDA','ADFGAFD','ADFDFFDDFG','AHUUERR','>ness is another','ADFGGGGH',
'HHHDFDA']
```

how would you be able to look at all lines that start with '>' and then if they have one of the names name_list then include the line with the '>' and also the sequences following it (sequences following will always be in upper) in two separate lists

```
#example output file

name_list = ['>link is the first','>ganon is the fourth','>volvagia is the last']
seq_list = ['OIGFHFHAGIUUIIUFG','ADGGHHHHHH','AFGDAAFGDAADFGAFDADFDFFDDFGAHUUERR']
```

i would rather not use a dictionary to do this as i've been prompted to do in similar situations

so what i have so far is:

```
for line,name in zip(data,query):
    if bool(line[0] == '>' and re.search(name,line))==True:
        #but then i'm stuck because len(query) and len(data) are not equal
```

.... any help would be greatly appreciated``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = []
names = ['link', 'zelda', 'saria', 'ganon', 'volvagia']
lines = iter(data)
for line in lines:
    while line.startswith(">") and any(name in line for name in names):
        name = line
        upper_seq = []
        for line in lines:
            if not line.isupper():
                break
            upper_seq.append(line)
        else:
            line = "" # guard against infinite loop at EOF 

        result.append((name, ''.join(upper_seq)))
```

If there are many names then `set()` might be faster to find names in line instead of `any(...)`:

```
names = set(names)
# ...
    if line.startswith(">") and names.intersection(line[1:].split()):
        # ...
```

#### Result

```
[('>link is the first', 'OIGFHFHAGIUUIIUFG'),
 ('>ganon is the fourth', 'ADGGHHHHHH'),
 ('>volvagia is the last', 'AFGDAAFGDAADFGAFDADFDFFDDFGAHUUERR')]
```

Comment: sir you are a life saver. i need to figure out how 'while' statements work they confuse me still

Answer (score 0):

use a list comprehension

```
print [line for line in lines if line.startswith(">") and set(my_words).intersection(line[1:].split())]
```

this decomposes to a for loop as follows

```
matched_line = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(">") and set(my_words).intersection(line[1:].split()):
       matched_lines.append(line)
```

using a set intersection should be significantly faster than looping over each word in the list and seeign if it is in the string

```
>>> print [line for line in data if line.startswith(">") and set(query).intersection(line[1:].split())]
['>link is the first', '>ganon is the fourth', '>volvagia is the last']
```

Comment: awesome.  i understand how this works and i've never used list comprehension before.  what do you suppose i should do to gather the sequences that follow those matched_lines ?

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways to do this, but I think this method might be the easiest for you to understand:

```
>>> found_lines = []
>>> sequences = []
>>> for line in data:
...     if line.startswith(">"):
...         for name in query:
...             if name in line:
...                 found_lines.append(line)
...     else:
...         sequences.append(line)
>>> print found_lines
['>link is the first', '>ganon is the fourth', '>volvagia is the last']
>>>
```

Always start simple, and think your way through the problem. What's the first thing you need to do? You want to loop over every line in `data` (`for line in data`).

For each of those lines, you want to check if it starts with `>`. (`if line.startswith(">")`). If it doesn't start with that character, then we can assume it's a "sequence", and add it to the `sequences` list (`sequences.append(line)`)

If it does, then you want to check if any of the names in `query` appear in that line. What's the easiest way to do that? Loop over every one of the names (`for name in query`), and check it by itself (`if name in line`)

Comment: wouldn't else: sequences.append(line) gather all of the lines that do not start with ">" ? i need to categorize them by gathering all of the lines of sequence that follow the "found_line"  up until (and not including) the next line that startswith(">")