# Organizing list of strings by '>names' and 'sequences'. Python

Tags: python, string, list, while-loop, append

So I have a list of strings read from a file (query).  I want to append all the lines that start with ">" to a list called name_list and all of the alphabetical characters following it (but before the next ">" line) to a list.  This is very similar question that I had to before concerning set theory but when I tried to manipulate the **while loop**, it got caught in an infinite feedback loop ...

here is an example of the list of strings

```
query = [">mm10_refGene_NM_001011532 range=chr2:86084810-86085854 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none", 'caatgcctttgcctcactgataatttctattagtcttatcttatttcatt', 'ttactttgcagctgttaagacttgatgaaATGGCTGGAAGCAATGCCACT', 'GGTGTGACAGAATTCATTCTCTTGGGGTTTGCAGTCCAGAGAGAGGTAGA',">mm10_refGene_NM_001011534 range=chr2:85352995-85353924 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none", 'ATGGAACAAAGTAATGACACCAAAGTGACTGAATTCATTCTTCTGGGATT', 'TTCCGGACAGCACAAATCTTGGCACATTCTGTTCATAATATTTCTAATGA', 'TCTATGTTGTCACACTCATGGGTAACATTGGAATGATCGTACTCATCAAA']
```

this was the code that I have been working with:

```
name_list = []
seq_list = []

for line in query:

    while line.startswith(">"):
        name=line
        temp_seq=[]

        for line in query:
            if line.isalpha()==True:
                temp_seq.append(line)


            else:
                break
        name_list.append(name)
        seq_list.append(''.join(temp_seq))
```

example of output data:

```
name_list = [">mm10_refGene_NM_001011532 range=chr2:86084810-86085854 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none",">mm10_refGene_NM_001011534 range=chr2:85352995-85353924 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none"]

seq_list = ['caatgcctttgcctcactgataatttctattagtcttatcttatttcattttactttgcagctgttaagacttgatgaaATGGCTGGAAGCAATGCCACTGGTGTGACAGAATTCATTCTCTTGGGGTTTGCAGTCCAGAGAGAGGTAGA','ATGGAACAAAGTAATGACACCAAAGTGACTGAATTCATTCTTCTGGGATTTTCCGGACAGCACAAATCTTGGCACATTCTGTTCATAATATTTCTAATGATCTATGTTGTCACACTCATGGGTAACATTGGAATGATCGTACTCATCAAA']
```

Sorry if this is similar to ([Search for word (from list of words) in line (from list of lines) and append values to new list. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349121/search-for-word-from-list-of-words-in-line-from-list-of-lines-and-append-val)) and redundant in any way but I thought it would be a good question to help people who deal with this type of data.

Comment: This looks like you parsed a fasta file to get the two sequences. I know you are asking a question outside of the scope of it, but have you looked into http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

```
name_list = []
seq_list = []

lines = iter(query)
for line in lines:
    while line.startswith(">"):
        name = line
        temp_seq = []
        for line in lines:
            if line.isalpha():
                temp_seq.append(line)
            else:
                break
        name_list.append(name)
        seq_list.append(''.join(temp_seq))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of your code that loops through the elements of query one at a time:

```
name_list = []
seq_list = []

seq = ""
for line in query:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        if seq:
            seq_list.append(seq)
            seq = ""
        name_list.append(line)
    elif line.isalpha():
        seq = seq + line
seq_list.append(seq)
```

But, in the example you provided, `query` has a consistent pattern of "name", followed by 3 "sequences". If your data always follows this consistent pattern, then here's another way to do it. You can define a function called `grouper` ([taken from the itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)), which will let you read 4 elements of `query` at a time.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Now, for each 4 element "chunk" of `query`, you append the 1st element to "names", and concatenate the last 3 to append to "sequences":

```
names = []
sequences = []

for chunk in grouper(4, query):
    names.append(chunk[0])
    sequences.append(''.join(chunk[1:]))

print names
print sequences
```

Output:

```
[">mm10_refGene_NM_001011532 range=chr2:86084810-86085854 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none", ">mm10_refGene_NM_001011534 range=chr2:85352995-85353924 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none"]
['caatgcctttgcctcactgataatttctattagtcttatcttatttcattttactttgcagctgttaagacttgatgaaATGGCTGGAAGCAATGCCACTGGTGTGACAGAATTCATTCTCTTGGGGTTTGCAGTCCAGAGAGAGGTAGA', 'ATGGAACAAAGTAATGACACCAAAGTGACTGAATTCATTCTTCTGGGATTTTCCGGACAGCACAAATCTTGGCACATTCTGTTCATAATATTTCTAATGATCTATGTTGTCACACTCATGGGTAACATTGGAATGATCGTACTCATCAAA']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very straightforwardly with [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def name_seq_chunks(seq): 
    isheader = lambda l:l.startswith('>')
    header = None
    for startgroup, dataiter in groupby(seq, isheader):
        if startgroup is True:
            header = list(dataiter)[-1]
        elif startgroup is False:
            yield header, ''.join(dataiter)

print list(name_seq_chunks(query))
```

This will yield a list of tuples like `[('>header', 'caatgccttt...'), ...]`.  If you really want them separate you can just rezip the list:

```
names, seqs = zip(*name_seq_chunks(query))
```